# loop through each column and identify if filled out or not in another spark dataframe

Tags: loops, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark data frame that I wanted to copy the first 4 columns to a new dataframe and also iterate through the rest of the columns of the original dataframe and identify if null or notnull and fill the columns with 1 or 0, or filled/notfilled, whichever is more efficient in the new df. I have more than 15 columns.

```
+------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|col1  | col2  | col3   | col4  | col5  | col6  | col7   |
+------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|001   | 2501  |2022    | 4     |john   |smith  | null   |
+------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
```

what I expect to get is this:

```
+------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|col1  | col2  | col3   | col4  | col5  | col6  | col7   |
+------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|001   | 2501  |2022    | 4     |filled |filled |notfilled|
+------+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
```

When I tried to think 1/0 as a boolean, it tried the following:

```
df_filled = df.select(df.columns[0:4])

# loop through the rest of the columns and adds the column name to the new dataframe. Set the valuf of each cell to 1 if notnull from original dataframe and 0 if null
for col in df.columns[4:]:
    df_filled = df_filled .withColumn(col, df[col].isNotNull().cast('integer'))
```

or when I use the filled/notfilled with below:

```
df_filled.withColumn(i, when(df[i].isNull(),'notfilled').otherwise('filled'))
```

but I am getting an AnalysisExceptionError: (my numbering could be wrong, all made up)

```
AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) col1#11111 missing from col2#22222,col3#333333,col4#312324,col5#5234234,col6#123123in operator !Project [col1#1111, col2#22222, col3#333333, col4#312324, col5#5234234, cast(isnotnull(col3#22222) as int) AS col3#333333].;
```

when I initially converted to pandas, it worked, but it takes an hour for the 10GB data

```
df[col].apply(lambda x: 1 if pd.notnull(x) else 0)
```

it seems like there is a null data somewhere that the new df cannot map from the original df, or i could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just make a copy and override the columns with the new 1/0

```py
# Make a copy
df_filled = df.alias('df_filled')

# loop through the rest of the columns and adds the column name to the new dataframe. Set the valuf of each cell to 1 if notnull from original dataframe and 0 if null
for col in df_filled.columns[4:]:
    df_filled = df_filled.withColumn(col, df_filled[col].isNotNull().cast('integer')) 

df_filled.show()
```